# Using YAJL to pull a streaming API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, yajl

I'm trying to get YAJL working in my app - been testing it off the Twitter API and the Digg API and I can't seem to get it working.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Tapping into the Twitter streaming API using this code: (username/password removed)

```
max_allowed_errors = 1200
consecutive_errors = 0
while consecutive_errors < max_allowed_errors do
  url = URI.parse("https://[username]:[password]!@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json")
  begin
    Yajl::HttpStream.get(url) do |status|
      consecutive_errors = 0
     # puts status.inspect
    end
  rescue Yajl::HttpStream::InvalidContentType
    consecutive_errors += 1
  end
  sleep(0.25*consecutive_errors)
end
```

I get an error:

```
Yajl::HttpStream::HttpError in DashboardsController#streamit

Code 200 expected got 0
```

The error refers to this line:

```
Yajl::HttpStream.get(url) do |status|
```

I'd like to avoid API-specific gems so I can reuse code and tap into other APIs down the road (i.e. TweetStream).

Thanks in advance for the help! Let me know if you have any questions or if I can clarify this at all.

Oh! I'll note I'm open to other gems to manage streaming if you have recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue comes from the fact that when you are placing an HTTPS call, it needs to negotiate SSL.  If you look at the source you see:

```
    socket = opts.delete(:socket) || TCPSocket.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = "#{method} #{uri.path}#{uri.query ? "?"+uri.query : nil} HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

The source is here: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby/blob/master/lib/yajl/http_stream.rb

It seems that all it does is open a plain TCP socket.

It probably should use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html for ssl

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into this and alternatives to handle streaming.

Comment: You can thank me by hitting that little up arrow for providing you a helpful answer :)

Comment: +1 for you. I haven't gotten SSL to work using YAJL, but I tried switching to EventMachine and got the SSL connection to take - just need a way to manage connections. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem and thanks. You may want to bring this up to the YAJL developers as it seems like a pretty simple fix for them.